# Как убрать реверс в анимации

Tags: android, android-animation

Есть анимация которая сдвигает элемент по оси Х. Каким образом можно убрать реверс у такой анимации,  т.е. что бы она работала только в одном направлении, а в конце анимации я закрепил положение элемента с помощью LayoutParams().

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-400"
        android:duration="700"/>

</set>
```

Comment: так она сейчас работает в одном направлении, от начального положения, а потом влево. Но лучше не использовать абсолютное значение, на разных устройствах будет выглядеть по разному. По окончанию вернется на свою позицию. В чем вопрос тогда?

Comment: по поводу абсолютных  значений я уже думал, мне такой вариант конечно же не подходит, нужно будет как то динамически туда вставлять значение. И похоже эффект который я наблюдаю - это не реверс, а как раз ошибка в значениях. Каким образом можно задать значения для анимации программно, или как написать такую же анимацию программо?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для такой простой анимации, можно использовать ViewPropertyAnimator, где v - ваш view элемент. Пример аналогичен Вашему.

```
v.animate().translationX(-400).setDuration(700);
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте для этих целей `ObjectAnimator` 
http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html